# France's Public Holidays' Puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle, combinatorics

In France, there are 11 public holidays. As a French employee who enjoys public holidays on week days, you want to know if it is possible that all of the 11 public holidays during one year fall on week days.

**The puzzle is to answer this question, and more precisely, if the answer is no, to prove why and if the answer is yes, to give the next following year this will happen starting from 2019 where there are 10 bank holidays on week days.**

The following rules apply to the [11 French holidays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_France) :

1. **New Year's Day** : 1st of January
2. **Easter Monday** : Monday following Easter Sunday which is the next Sunday after the first full moon beginning from Spring's Equinox (approximately 21 march).
3. **Labour Day** : 1st of May
4. **Victory in Europe Day** : 8th of May
5. **Ascension Day** : 39 days after Easter Sunday
6. **Whit Monday** : 50 days after Easter Sunday
7. **Bastille Day** : 14th of July
8. **Assumption of Mary to Heaven** : 15th of August
9. **All Saints' Day** : 1st of November
10. **Armistice Day** : 11th of November
11. **Christmas Day** : 25th of December

Comment: And as some might know, there are revendications for [the first of May not being a Sunday anymore, or it becoming the second of May](https://youtu.be/a1dRPmFMQZc?t=237)... :-) ("et que le 1er mai ne tombe plus un dimanche, ou alors que ça devienne le 2 mai. Mets-le ça aussi, c'est important...")

Comment: Great video! Très bonne référence @Jenayah haha !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all,

> 2 and 6 always fall on a Monday, and 5 on a Thursday. So these can be ignored.

It will probably make a difference

> if it's a leap year or not, but New Year's Day is the only day before the end of February.

So let's concentrate on the other ones

> and check which [day of year](https://www.epochconverter.com/days/2019) they are:
>  May 1st: 121 (=2 mod 7)
>  May 8st: 128 (=2 mod 7)
>  July 14th: 195 (=6 mod 7)
>  August 15th: 227 (=2 mod 7)
>  November 1st: 305 (=4 mod 7)
>  November 11th: 315 (=0 mod 7)
>  In leap years like 2020, the values will be one higher (resp. 3, 3, 0, 3, 5, 1 mod 7).

We can already stop here;

> In a given year, weekends will always fall on two consecutive values mod 7 (e.g. 0 and 1). The remaining slots (1, 3 and 5 for non-leap years; 2, 4 and 6 for leap years) are non-consecutive,

so

> it is **not possible** that all of the 11 public holidays during one year fall on week days.

Comment: Clear and precise solution as well as first answer, congrats !

Comment: As a French employee which enjoys public holidays on week days, this answer saddens me. +1 for the hard truth.

Comment: @Abhilashk no, the first mentioned values (2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 0) are for 2019, a non-leap year. So the remaining slots are 1, 3 and 5.

Answer (score 17):

Answer:

> It's impossible.

Consider for instance

> 1st of January (Day **1** of the year); 1st of May (day **121**); July 14th (day **195**); August 15 (day **227**); 1st of November (day **305**).

You get the sequence of numbers

> $1, 121, 195, 227, 305$ which, reduced modulo $7$, gives $1, 2, 6, 3, 4$. In case of a leap year, the sequence is $1, 122, 196, 228, 306$ which reduces to $1, 3, 7, 4, 5$.

In both cases,

> all days of the weeks are covered except two, but these two are not consecutive, so they can't possibly correspond to Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: I can't choose two answers to my question and I decided to choose the first correct answer but yours is also exact and clear ;) You got my +1

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Apologies for the poor formatting, I've been trying to figure this out for forever. Any help is appreciated in hiding the code.

I can't fully, aptly answer as I don't want to steal from anyone above. My reasoning would be

> "because the computer says it is simply not true".

Some very poorly written code (Python 3.x):

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

def calc_easter(year):
    a = year % 19
    b = year//100
    c = year % 100
    d = (19 * a + b - b // 4 - ((b - (b + 8) // 25 + 1) // 3) + 15) % 30
    e = (32 + 2 * (b % 4) + 2 * (c // 4) - d - (c % 4)) % 7
    f = d + e - 7 * ((a + 11 * d + 22 * e) // 451) + 114
    month = f // 31
    day = f % 31 + 1    
    return date(year, month, day)

completed = 0
startyear = 2019

while completed == 0 and startyear < 3000:

startyear = startyear
figureitout = 0
holidays = 0

easterdate = calc_easter(startyear)  
newyears = datetime.datetime(startyear, 1,1)
easterdate = calc_easter(startyear)
easterd = easterdate + timedelta(days=1)
labourday = datetime.datetime(startyear, 5, 1)
vday = labourday + timedelta(days=7)
aday = easterdate + timedelta(days = 39)
wmon = aday + timedelta(days = 11)
bday = datetime.datetime(startyear, 7, 14)
amday = datetime.datetime(startyear, 8, 15)
asday = datetime.datetime(startyear, 11, 1)
armday = datetime.datetime(startyear, 11, 11)
cday = datetime.datetime(startyear, 12, 25)

bigdict = [newyears, easterd, labourday, vday, aday, wmon, bday, amday, asday, armday, cday]

for holiday in bigdict:

    if holiday.weekday() <= 4:
        figureitout = figureitout +1
        holidays = holidays + 1
        if figureitout >= 12 and holidays < 11:
            startyear = startyear + 1
            completed = 0
        if figureitout > 12 and holidays == 11:
            startyear = startyear + 1
            completed = 0
    else:
        figureitout = figureitout +2
        holidays = holidays + 1
        if figureitout >= 12 and holidays < 11:
            startyear = startyear + 1
            completed = 0
        if figureitout > 12 and holidays == 11:
            startyear = startyear + 1
            completed = 0

    if figureitout == 12 and holidays == 11 or figureitout == 11 and holidays == 11:
        if figureitout == 12:
            holidays = 10
            print("Holidays = " + str(holidays) + " in the year " + str(startyear))
            startyear = startyear + 1
            recurse = 1
        if figureitout == 11:
            holidays = 11
            print("Holidays = " + str(holidays) + " in the year " + str(startyear))
            startyear = startyear + 1
```

Explanation of the code:

> The Easter calculation function is an implementation of Butcher's algorithm.
> The starting year, obviously, is 2019. Functions are given for each of the holidays based on either their calendar dates or respective dates to already calculated holidays. The "for holiday in bigdict" loops through the holidays and determines the weekday value they fall on - in this case, Monday is 0, Tuesday is 1, etc. That gives allowable values from 0 to 4. If the weekday returns one of these values, +1 is added to "figureitout" which starts at 0. If the value is greater than 4, +2 is added. The reason I chose this was to allow for a single holiday that doesn't fall on a weekday, like the current year specified in the question. If figureitout adds up to 11 and the number of holiday is 11, the "holidays" value is 11. If figureitout adds up to 12, the "holidays" value is 10, as 10(1) + 2 = 12. If figureitout reaches 12 prior to the number of holidays reaching 11, the values are reset and the starting year is incremented. The output is a list for all year values under 3000 that satisfy one of the two outcomes.

The resulting output:

> Holidays = 10 in the year 2019  Holidays = 10 in the year 2025  Holidays = 10 in the year 2030  Holidays = 10 in the year 2031  Holidays = 10 in the year 2042  Holidays = 10 in the year 2047  Holidays = 10 in the year 2053  Holidays = 10 in the year 2058  Holidays = 10 in the year 2059  Holidays = 10 in the year 2070  Holidays = 10 in the year 2075  Holidays = 10 in the year 2081  Holidays = 10 in the year 2086  Holidays = 10 in the year 2087  Holidays = 10 in the year 2098  Holidays = 10 in the year 2104  Holidays = 10 in the year 2110  Holidays = 10 in the year 2115  Holidays = 10 in the year 2121  Holidays = 10 in the year 2126  Holidays = 10 in the year 2127  Holidays = 10 in the year 2138  Holidays = 10 in the year 2143  Holidays = 10 in the year 2149  Holidays = 10 in the year 2154  Holidays = 10 in the year 2155  Holidays = 10 in the year 2166  Holidays = 10 in the year 2171  Holidays = 10 in the year 2177  Holidays = 10 in the year 2182  Holidays = 10 in the year 2183  Holidays = 10 in the year 2194  Holidays = 10 in the year 2199  Holidays = 10 in the year 2200  Holidays = 10 in the year 2206  Holidays = 10 in the year 2211  Holidays = 10 in the year 2217  Holidays = 10 in the year 2222  Holidays = 10 in the year 2223  Holidays = 10 in the year 2234  Holidays = 10 in the year 2239  Holidays = 10 in the year 2245  Holidays = 10 in the year 2250  Holidays = 10 in the year 2251  Holidays = 10 in the year 2262  Holidays = 10 in the year 2267  Holidays = 10 in the year 2273  Holidays = 10 in the year 2278  Holidays = 10 in the year 2279  Holidays = 10 in the year 2290  Holidays = 10 in the year 2295  Holidays = 10 in the year 2301  Holidays = 10 in the year 2302  Holidays = 10 in the year 2307  Holidays = 10 in the year 2313  Holidays = 10 in the year 2318  Holidays = 10 in the year 2319  Holidays = 10 in the year 2330  Holidays = 10 in the year 2335  Holidays = 10 in the year 2341  Holidays = 10 in the year 2346  Holidays = 10 in the year 2347  Holidays = 10 in the year 2358  Holidays = 10 in the year 2363  Holidays = 10 in the year 2369  Holidays = 10 in the year 2374  Holidays = 10 in the year 2375  Holidays = 10 in the year 2386  Holidays = 10 in the year 2391  Holidays = 10 in the year 2397  Holidays = 10 in the year 2402  Holidays = 10 in the year 2403  Holidays = 10 in the year 2414  Holidays = 10 in the year 2419  Holidays = 10 in the year 2425  Holidays = 10 in the year 2430  Holidays = 10 in the year 2431  Holidays = 10 in the year 2442  Holidays = 10 in the year 2447  Holidays = 10 in the year 2453  Holidays = 10 in the year 2458  Holidays = 10 in the year 2459  Holidays = 10 in the year 2470  Holidays = 10 in the year 2475  Holidays = 10 in the year 2481  Holidays = 10 in the year 2486  Holidays = 10 in the year 2487  Holidays = 10 in the year 2498  Holidays = 10 in the year 2504  Holidays = 10 in the year 2510  Holidays = 10 in the year 2515  Holidays = 10 in the year 2521  Holidays = 10 in the year 2526  Holidays = 10 in the year 2527  Holidays = 10 in the year 2538  Holidays = 10 in the year 2543  Holidays = 10 in the year 2549  Holidays = 10 in the year 2554  Holidays = 10 in the year 2555  Holidays = 10 in the year 2566  Holidays = 10 in the year 2571  Holidays = 10 in the year 2577  Holidays = 10 in the year 2582  Holidays = 10 in the year 2583  Holidays = 10 in the year 2594  Holidays = 10 in the year 2599  Holidays = 10 in the year 2600  Holidays = 10 in the year 2606  Holidays = 10 in the year 2611  Holidays = 10 in the year 2617  Holidays = 10 in the year 2622  Holidays = 10 in the year 2623  Holidays = 10 in the year 2634  Holidays = 10 in the year 2639  Holidays = 10 in the year 2645  Holidays = 10 in the year 2650  Holidays = 10 in the year 2651  Holidays = 10 in the year 2662  Holidays = 10 in the year 2667  Holidays = 10 in the year 2673  Holidays = 10 in the year 2678  Holidays = 10 in the year 2679  Holidays = 10 in the year 2690  Holidays = 10 in the year 2695  Holidays = 10 in the year 2701  Holidays = 10 in the year 2702  Holidays = 10 in the year 2707  Holidays = 10 in the year 2713  Holidays = 10 in the year 2718  Holidays = 10 in the year 2719  Holidays = 10 in the year 2730  Holidays = 10 in the year 2735  Holidays = 10 in the year 2741  Holidays = 10 in the year 2746  Holidays = 10 in the year 2747  Holidays = 10 in the year 2758  Holidays = 10 in the year 2763  Holidays = 10 in the year 2769  Holidays = 10 in the year 2774  Holidays = 10 in the year 2775  Holidays = 10 in the year 2786  Holidays = 10 in the year 2791  Holidays = 10 in the year 2797  Holidays = 10 in the year 2802  Holidays = 10 in the year 2803  Holidays = 10 in the year 2814  Holidays = 10 in the year 2819  Holidays = 10 in the year 2825  Holidays = 10 in the year 2830  Holidays = 10 in the year 2831  Holidays = 10 in the year 2842  Holidays = 10 in the year 2847  Holidays = 10 in the year 2853  Holidays = 10 in the year 2858  Holidays = 10 in the year 2859  Holidays = 10 in the year 2870  Holidays = 10 in the year 2875  Holidays = 10 in the year 2881  Holidays = 10 in the year 2886  Holidays = 10 in the year 2887  Holidays = 10 in the year 2898  Holidays = 10 in the year 2904  Holidays = 10 in the year 2910  Holidays = 10 in the year 2915  Holidays = 10 in the year 2921  Holidays = 10 in the year 2926  Holidays = 10 in the year 2927  Holidays = 10 in the year 2938  Holidays = 10 in the year 2943  Holidays = 10 in the year 2949  Holidays = 10 in the year 2954  Holidays = 10 in the year 2955  Holidays = 10 in the year 2966  Holidays = 10 in the year 2971  Holidays = 10 in the year 2977  Holidays = 10 in the year 2982  Holidays = 10 in the year 2983  Holidays = 10 in the year 2994  Holidays = 10 in the year 2999

As we can see:

> It appears impossible to have all 11 holidays land on a weekday.

Comment: @J.Khamphousone thanks for the suggestion! I'll add it right away

Comment: I like the idea of being helped with computers ;) if it won't happen until year 3000 it'll may never happen. And in the context of the puzzle, It'll pratically won't matter if it'll happen when the French employee won't work anymore, neither his kids, grandkids  etc. ^^
I +1 you for the idea. Perhaps you should comment a bit more your code and make it a bit clearer, if you have the time and you're willling to :p

Comment: @J.Khamphousone can do, coming right up!

Comment: @J.Khamphousone hopefully that's clear enough and explains my thought process.